# How to associate public Ip Address with an existing domain name

Tags: azure, dns, azure-virtual-machine, dnsmasq

i don t understand how DNS works!

I have an public IP address bouaght from AZURE and Now my website already has a domain name (myWebsite.com) that is tied to my old server.

Now I have bought a new VM in AZURE ( it is a Ubuntu).

Now, how can i change that my domain name (myWebsite.com) to point now to the new Public IP ADDRESS of my VM at azure.

Do i have to do it in the command line or not?
??

Comment: You need check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-custom-domain-name-portal).

Comment: According to your scenario, you could select `Add an A record for your custom domain`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should gave a look at the article that Walter linked to - that covers the full scenario end to end.

I assume that you're using Azure Resource Manager, as you've specifically mentioned the Public IP Address resource. You don't mention if you've configured a DNS name for that Public IP Address, or if it has a static or dynamic IP address. You can find the full details for the Public IP Address resource here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/network/create-or-update-a-public-ip-address

You're going to need to log into the service on which you're hosting myWebsite.com and create a DNS record. What that record is depends on the below:

-if you need users to hit the zone apex and resolve your website (i.e. myWebsite.com), then you need to ensure that the Public IP Address is static, and create an A record to that IP address. This will look like:
myWebsite.com A {The static Public IP Address}

-if users will instead be using a sub-domain (i.e. www.myWebsite.com), then you should add a DNS name to the Public IP Address, and then create a CNAME from the sub-domain that users will hit to that DNS name. This will look like: www.myWebsite.com CNAME {your service ename}.{region}.cloudapp.azure.com

To expand on the reasoning for the above -

- Using an A record with a dynamic IP address means that you'd have to update 
  the DNS record any time the IP changed during which time your website is effectively offline
- Creating a CNAME record is not supported for the zone root or apex (i.e. myWebsite.com) as per the RFCs

Please note that there may be a small charge for static Public IP Addresses. See here for more information:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/

Regards,
Stephen Malone - Azure Networking

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to understand DNS to configure that, but basically you need to point you dns A record to Azure IP, or better point your CNAME record to Azure DNS Name of your public IP, that way when it will change it won't break things.

There are a lot of instructtions how to change your DNS records depending on your provider (GoDaddy or something else)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but form me it is stil not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your DNS Server, where you created your domain name, click on +Record Set and create a A record using your new IP address, wait for the TTL time, and you should be able to connect